# how to setup node_path for hubot

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, hubot

I'm using hubot (specifically hubot-hipchat) and want to use the https://github.com/scriby/asyncblock node module. What is the correct way to import/require a node module in hubot?

I cd to where I installed hubot (~/hubot) and did

Edit hubot/packages.json added hubot-hipchat,asyncblock to the dependencies section.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "hubot-hipchat": ">= 1.0.4",
    "hubot": "2.1.4",
    "hubot-scripts": ">=2.0.4",
    "optparse": "1.0.3",
    "asyncblock": "2.0.8"
  }
```

I then do the following in my scripts/test.coffee script:

```
asyncblock = require('asyncblock')
```

When I start hubot, I get the error: ERROR Error: Cannot find module 'asyncblock'

~/hubot/node_modules/asyncblock exists.  So then I try to do :

```
require.paths.push('/home/ubuntu/hubot/node_modules')
```

Now I don't get the can't find error, but I get a new one:

```
ERROR Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm just trying to exec a system command on the ubuntu server where I have hubot running:

```
  asyncblock((flow) ->
    exec('node -v', flow.add())
    result = flow.wait()
    msg.send result
  )
```

Edit: 
so if I set the NODE_PATH env var to the following it works:

```
env NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/share/javascript:/home/ubuntu/hubot/node_modules"
```

Why does it not by convention look in hubot/node_modules ??

Comment: I can answer part of your question: `require.paths` was removed in Node 0.5. Any articles or source code you come across that uses `require.paths.push` is outdated. I assume you're on Node 0.6.x?

Comment: node -v: v0.6.17. Yep I'm aware its deprecated/removed. What confuses me is why does it not find the module in ./node_modules - as it finds my other modules in that dir (like hubot-hipchat) just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your script with the `require('asyncblock')`? Is it in a subdirectory of `~/hubot`? If not, its `require` function won't look in `~/hubot/node_modules`.

Check the value of `module.paths` from that script to see all of the non-global paths that script's `require` looks at.

Comment: my coffeescript file is in ~/hubot/scripts. This script is also using methods from hubot-hipchat (which is in ~/hubot/node_modules).  Not sure why it wouldn't find ~/hubot/node_modules/asyncblock

Comment: Are there any symlinks involved here? That is, is `~/hubot/scripts` a real directory and is `~/hubot/scripts/test.coffee` a real file? Again, please report the value of `module.paths` from `test.coffee`.

Comment: ~/hubot/scripts is a real dir. ~/hubot/scripts/deploy.coffee (my script) is a symlink to deploy.coffee -> /home/ubuntu/git/mln-admin/hubot/scripts/deploy.coffee.  However in this script, as mentioned above, I use objects in ~/hubot/node_modules/hubot-hipchat/ for example

module.paths is (some dont exist):

/home/ubuntu/git/mln-admin/hubot/scripts/node_modules,/home/ubuntu/git/mln-admin/hubot/node_modules,/home/ubuntu/git/mln-admin/node_modules,/home/ubuntu/git/node_modules,/home/ubuntu/node_modules,/home/node_modules,/node_modules

Comment: So wait, why is `/home/ubuntu/hubot/node_modules` the path you added to `NODE_PATH` to get it to work but `/home/ubuntu/git/mln-admin/hubot/node_modules` is the path in `module.paths`? Does `/home/ubuntu/git/mln-admin/hubot/node_modules` contain an `asyncblock` subdirectory with a `package.json` and `lib/asyncblock.js`?

Comment: because /home/ubuntu/hubot/node_modules is where hubot is installed as well as hubot-hipchat and asyncblock. ~ in question above and comments is '/home/ubuntu'. /home/ubuntu/hubot/scripts/deploy.coffee is my script.  Yes /home/ubuntu/git/mln-admin/hubot/node_modules/lib/asyncblock.js exists and can be used when set the NODE_PATH env var.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are referencing an npm module that is not added to your project. From the root of your hubot folder run the following code:

```
npm install --save asyncblock
```

This will save the asyncblock as a dependency in the package.json file.
Thus if you deploy to heroku or open shift or any other cloud service, the service will know to automatically download the module so its available to your robot.

After completing the above task

```
asyncblock= require 'asyncblock'
```

is correct using coffee-script

Answer (score -1):

It's much simpler to do this. I'm using hubot and hipchat too. All you need to do is:

```
cd hubot-dir;
npm install asyncblock
```

Here's what you should observe:

```
$ npm install asyncblock
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asyncblock
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/asyncblock
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asyncblock/-/asyncblock-2.0.9.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/asyncblock/-/asyncblock-2.0.9.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/0.6.7
npm http GET https://github.com/scriby/UglifyJS/tarball/1.2.5-6
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/0.6.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-0.6.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-0.6.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://github.com/scriby/UglifyJS/tarball/1.2.5-6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp/-/node-gyp-0.4.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp/-/node-gyp-0.4.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi/-/ansi-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-1.1.8.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream/-/fstream-0.1.18.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-2.0.2.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-3.1.9.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-1.0.14.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/which/-/which-1.0.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-0.1.13.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-1.1.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi/-/ansi-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream/-/fstream-0.1.18.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-2.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-3.1.9.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-1.0.14.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/which/-/which-1.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-0.1.13.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-1.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream/-/block-stream-0.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-1.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream/-/block-stream-0.0.5.tgz

fibers@0.6.7 install /tmp/hubot/node_modules/asyncblock/node_modules/fibers
node ./build.js

`linux-ia32` exists; skipping build
asyncblock@2.0.9 ./node_modules/asyncblock
├── uglify-js_scriby@1.2.5-6
└── fibers@0.6.7 (node-gyp@0.4.5)
```